# Can not access memory card on HTC ONE V

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

I am developing and testing a simple video player example in Android. Code is given below:

```
VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

vid.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
vid.start();
vid.requestFocus();
```

I am using HTC ONE V. When I run this on my phone I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line where I set the path of video (i.e. `setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4")`). I think there is problem in accessing the memory card.

So can anyone kindly tell that is the way to access memory card on HTC ONE V different from other phones? And if yes then how to access the memory card HTC ONE V.

Comment: Post your Logcat error . @ which line it shows null pointer exception

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.test.media/my.test.media.MyVideoPlayer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at my.test.media.MyVideoPlayer.onCreate(MyVideoPlayer.java:40)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2158)
... 11 more

Comment: Post MyVideoPlayer.java:40 Line number code . Post your entire activity code and xml file

Comment: Problem is solved. Actually I was trying to play video on phone while it was connected to the PC (even when I played directly from card while phone was connected, an error came saying that phone was being used as a USB), when I disconnected it, then it started palying. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting NullpointerException on the line

```
vid.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
```

then that indicates vid is null.

So make sure `setContentView` is done in `Oncreate` before you call findviewbyid and make sure R.id.videoView1 is present in the Layout that you have set.

As others have pointed do not hard code sdcard path.

Comment: Thank, I was missing setContentView and now I wrote that before this code, so Exception is not coming, but now it gives error on mobile phone says "Cannot play video. Sorry this video cannot be played"

Comment: are you using /sdcard/myvideo.mp4 or using getExternalstoragedirectory. For now try hard coding the exact path

Comment: I have tried both, /sdcard/myvideo.mp4 and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/myvideo.mp4", but it gives same error

Comment: but when I play that video directly from card, then it is played

Comment: then you should check the logs. See if it showing anything of importance

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
vid.setVideoPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+filename);
```

instead of

```
vid.setVideoPath("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
```

Comment: I did so, but even then it gives NullPointerException